# Does Twisted disownServiceParent delete all active connections

Tags: python, twisted

I have a python script that runs constantly, listening for TCP connections. I would like to close all connections at the end of each day.

I create my services with:
rendererService = internet.TCPServer(1945,f.getFactory(Renderer))
rendererService.setServiceParent(serviceCollection)

Every new Renderer is also referenced in a dictionary that is initiated at startup: renderers

To close all connections, I schedule it to run:

```
rendererService.disownServiceParent()
renderers = {}
```

Will this guarantee that all connections are shutdown and all objects are destroyed, even if they were in the progress of receiving/sending data?
Will it wait for the data transmission/reception to end before closing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

If you want to close all the connections, you will have to maintain a list of the transports created.

Comment: ok. so instead of disownServiceParent, if I do rendererService.stopService(), that would close the connection and I'll just serviceCollection.startService() when I want to continue, right?

From your reply, i'm not sure if I need to delete all the protocols that were created by the factory and associated with the service. I didn't find any way to remove a protocol.

Comment: to be more clear on my intention, I'm not worried about the connection, I'm worried that all the instances made by the factory would become ghosts and accumulate. I need to remove them at the end of the day...

Comment: No, `rendererService.stopService` will not close the connections.  If you want to close all the connections, you will have to maintain a list of all the transports created.  And then call `loseConnection` on each of them.